# Android Fragment Errors

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using below code to use fragment. I am developing it first time. Below code give me this error while I run code in emultor 4.2 or phone with android 2.3.3.

**Error**
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.fragmentdemo-2.apk]**

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    }
}
```

ArticleFragment.java

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    public ArticleFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

HeadlinesFragment.java

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends Fragment {
    public HeadlinesFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.head_lines_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

news_articles.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/head_lines_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdemo.HeadlinesFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

article_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FragmentDemo" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Articla-1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Articla-2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

headlines_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Today's HeadLines"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fragmentdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fragmentdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did this package `com.example.android.fragments` exists?

Comment: no only "com.example.fragmentdemo" this package is exists.

Comment: @nil then that is the location of your Article Fragment... `com.example.fragmentdemo.ArticleFragment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `news_article.xml` you have written

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />
```

does `com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment` really exist?
I am guessing by looking at another fragment it should be `com.example.fragmentdemo.ArticleFragment`

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest to me that in your news_articles.xml file you aren't pointing to the correct location of your ArticlesFragment class.

Have a look at your file structure and the package your ArticleFragment is in and make sure it matches the path you are specifying in your xml file.

**EDIT**

From a comment on another answer I can see that the package you have specified `ArticleFragment` belongs to doesn't exist.

Change the path to your class in you main xml to `com.example.fragmentdemo.ArticleFragment`

Answer (score 0):

dont user Fragment tags.

use com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment
instead.
I am not clear about your path. It should 
"mypackage.ArticleFragment"